# Visualfoce pages in profile are not added to profile after installation

Tags: salesforcedx, postinstall

How do I add permission to access visual force pages for individual profiles? Those profiles will be selected at the time of installation and I am expecting the pages I include in the profiles in the source code be added in those profile's list of visual force pages access.

I have added visual force pages in the profile in source code. I created 2nd gen managed package. After installation, those pages are not added to the selected profiles.
Then if I go to the profile and add those pages it works.
This is my first app. Is there a specific way to add / enable visual force page to be included in the profiles?

Comment: Did you try to select all user while installing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MIXDML when installing i selected individual profiles. The visual force pages where not getting added to the profile. 

I have to go add them in the profile manually after installation for those profile to have access to those visual force pages. 
Is this normal way to add access to visual force pages? This is my first app.

Answer (score 2):

Packaging Profiles is ... really weird. I think this is what `MIX DML` was alluding to in their question in the comments.

There's two ways you'll see this behavior on package install, *provided you install via the UI* (more below). When you package Profiles, on install, you'll be asked to select which users you want to install for. This determines which Profiles in the org your package's components will be added to. You'll also get an opportunity to associate the custom Profiles in your package with Profiles in the target org. Doing so merges the permission settings in your package with those target profiles.

If you install your package via the API, these steps don't happen. A default will be selected for you as far as Profiles to enable (All Users is the API default, but I don't know what `sfdx` does off the top of my head), and you won't get a chance to map packaged Profiles - they just vanish.

Long story short: avoid packaging Profiles. Give serious consideration to packaging Permission Sets instead, which have their own quirks (can't permission master-detail children of standard objects; can't permission standard objects at all, can't ship user permissions), but are overall much more understandable than Profiles.